# How to concatenate pandas dataframes with multiple level columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are several DataFrames like this shape.

```py
data = {'AAA': DataFrame, 'BBB': DataFrame, ...}
```

Each of DataFrame is like below.

```py
Date        A  B  C  D
2022-02-14  1  5  2  9
...
2022-02-14  2  5  8  7
```

I want to concatenate them like this.

```py
ATTR          A         B         C         D
SYMBOL      AAA  BBB  AAA  BBB  AAA  BBB  AAA  BBB
Date
2022-02-14    1    2    5    9    2    4    9    2
...
2022-02-14    2    6    5    3    8    6    7    3
```

When I used pandas `1.3.5`, I did this.

```py
data = pd.concat(data, sort=True).unstack(level=0)
data.columns.names = ['ATTR', 'SYMBOL']
```

But, in pandas `1.4.0`, I don't know how to do it.

Please help me out. I wasted many hours on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is problem duplicated `DatetimeIndex`, so `unstack` failed. Possible solution is add counter level to index by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and lasr remove helper level by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
data = pd.concat(data, sort=True)

data = pd.concat(data, sort=True)
data = (data.set_index(data.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True)
            .unstack(level=0)
            .droplevel(-1))
print (data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well. I will study with your guidance.